# StackOverflowException on a context menu strip item (Tool strip menu item)

Tags: c#, exception

## The concept:

OK, I have a *context menu strip* with one item (tool strip menu item), nothing special. I added a "click" event, everything worked the last time the application didn't thrown any exception, the context menu strip item BUT I forgot to mention that the item that I talk about is a child of another item. This another item is the first item you see in the context menu strip.

## Exception:

So now, on the exception, the problem: I debug my application, my Form1 is working normally, I click on a button that will show the Form where is the context menu strip that I talked about earlier, the Form didn't want to open, I saw the debug diagnostic tool where you can see how much the application use in RAM, I saw it was starting to take my PC RAM (100 MB), normally it takes 30 MB of RAM but that's way too much until it reached the limit, 180 MB of RAM for my application, the **StackOverflowException** where the message says "". Yes, it is blank because there is no message, only the exception name in bold (**StackOverflowException**: ). I didn't find anything in my case of this **StackOverflowException** because the people that have this exception have multiple items on their context menu strip.

## I tried:

Create another context menu strip, same text, same items, same click event, delete the old one, debug = same exception... Tried Google because I don't have any other idea = not my case.

## More info:

The line of code where I have this exception is where it is declaring the text of the item. I don't see the matter with "StackOverflowException" and "Open in explorer" <- the text.

## The code where the exception is thrown:

```
//FormName.Designer.cs

//
// openInExplorerTSMI
//
this.openInExplorerTSMI.CheckOnClick = false;
this.openInExplorerTSMI.Name = "openInExplorerTSMI";
this.openInExplorerTSMI.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(198, 22);
this.openInExplorerTSMI.Text = "Open in explorer"; //StackOverflowException here.
this.openInExplorerTSMI.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.openInExplorerTSMI_Click);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in openInExplorerTSMI_Click (or the method in which the exception stop) and repeat the process to generate the problem. Then, you can see lots of calls (one more each F5 you press) to that method with all the information: before the stack overflow. Probably the line that you see is wrong due to stack overflow: do the debug.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the context menu, SOE can strike anywhere.  Set a breakpoint on the form's InitializeComponent() call in the constructor.  The second time it hits you want to look at the Debug > Windows > Call Stack window to see how it got there.  A private variable of the form type with an initializer is the typical reason.

Comment: What is the code for `openInExplorerTSMI_Click`

Comment: Okay, I checked everything, there is no matter with the click event but with a custom class that is very important. The problem is the custom class doesn't want that we initialize with the constructor but with a method named "NewInstance" returning the class but I don't know why, after the "return" that return a new instance of that class it will redo "InitializeComponent" forever but my context menu strip doesn't needs it, and when I removed the context menu strip, it worked like everything. I can't find what's wrong with my context menu strip...